# Select Where In Join

Tags: mysql, where-clause

I want to get results from ids i already know. This is my attempt(pseudo):

```
SELECT * 
FROM main 
LEFT JOIN child 
WHERE main.id IN("1,2,3,4") 
ON main.id = child.main_id
```

How to get the childs from main by known ids from WHERE IN?

thx for help

Comment: it should be `LEFT JOIN child ON main.id = child.main_id WHERE main.id IN(1,2,3,4)`

Comment: And note that it's `(1,2,3,4)` and NOT `("1,2,3,4")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this, I think you have wrong syntax for what you need.

`SELECT * FROM main LEFT JOIN child ON main.id = child.main_id WHERE main.id IN(1,2,3,4)`

`ON` should be right after `JOIN` of both table and `IN` condition have no `"` wrapping around it.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to get could be reached by 2 options:

1.

```
SELECT * FROM main LEFT JOIN child ON main.id = child.main_id WHERE main.id IN(1,2,3,4);
```

remove the quotations.

or

2.

```
SELECT * FROM main JOIN child ON main.id = child.main_id AND main.id IN(1,2,3,4);
```

Comment: These queries give different results actually.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you're putting a String in the `IN` clausule, instead of a list of items.

The second problem is that the `ON` clausule must be right after the `JOIN` clausule, I guess. You can try it two different ways (I think you're kinda mixing them!):

```
SELECT * FROM main m, child c 
    WHERE m.id IN(1,2,3,4) AND c.main_id = m.id
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM main m LEFT JOIN child c ON m.id = c.main_id 
    WHERE main.id IN(1,2,3,4)
```

I hope this helps.